# Split string elements of a list with multiple separators/conditions. Any good Python library?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and I have been cleaning up a messy database using a combination of Google refine http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/ and Excel, however, I think that Python can do a better job as long as I am able to get some 'recipes' that I can reuse.

One variation of my problem is inconsistency in the 'Location' field of the database. About 95% of the data has the format in the list Location1, which I have been able to process with python in a more efficient way than with the use of Excel filters. However, I am looking for a python library or recipe that would allow me to work with all types of geo-locations in the database, maybe by defining patterns within the list.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Location1=['Washington, DC','Miami, FL','New York, NY']
Location2=['Kaslo/Nelson area (Canada), BC','Plymouth (UK/England)', 'Mexico, DF - outskirts-, (Mexico),']
Location3=['38.206471, -111.165271']

# This works for about 95% of the data, basically US addresses on Location1 type of List
CityList=[loc.split(',',1)[0] for loc in Location1]
StateList=[loc.split(',',1)[1] for loc in Location1]
```

Comment: A way around this problem could be to run each entry through a geocoder, then a reverse geocoder that would give you structured result. I'd suggest GeoNames for both: http://www.geonames.org

Comment: Use regular expressions to match each entry to a specific format, and then write code for each case. This is assuming that you can deal with the majority of the aberrant data with a manageable number of separate expressions, that is.

Comment: With regexes, you can capture groups of items. For example: the expression `"(\w+)\W*,\W*(\w{2})"` will match input such as `"Spokane, WA"`. With the capture groups in the regex, the `re` match object will yield a `groups()` like this `("Spokane", "WA")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're still having problems with this but here's an answer that I believe would work for you:

```
#location_regexes.py
import re
paren_pattern = re.compile(r"([^(]+, )?([^(]+?),? \(([^)]+)\)")

def parse_city_state(locations_list):
    city_list = []
    state_list = []
    coordinate_pairs = []
    for location in locations_list:
        if '(' in location:
            r = re.match(paren_pattern, location)
            city_list.append(r.group(2))
            state_list.append(r.group(3))
        elif location[0].isdigit() or location[0] == '-':
            coordinate_pairs.append(location.split(', '))
        else:
            city_list.append(location.split(', ', 1)[0])
            state_list.append(location.split(', ', 1)[1])
    return city_list, state_list, coordinate_pairs

#to demonstrate output
if __name__ == "__main__":
    locations = ['Washington, DC', 'Miami, FL', 'New York, NY',
                'Kaslo/Nelson area (Canada), BC', 'Plymouth (UK/England)',
                'Mexico, DF - outskirts-, (Mexico),', '38.206471, -111.165271']

    for parse_group in parse_city_state(locations):
        print parse_group
```

Output:

```
$ python location_regexes.py 
['Washington', 'Miami', 'New York', 'Kaslo/Nelson area', 'Plymouth', 'DF - outskirts-']
['DC', 'FL', 'NY', 'Canada', 'UK/England', 'Mexico']
[['38.206471', '-111.165271']]
```